# Starting mupltiple threads and collect the results

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an Interface for searching in some subsystems gathered by an ENUM. The Interface looks like this:

```java
public interface ReferenceController {

    public Map<String, ReferenceElement> searchElements(String searchField, List<String> searchItems, SystemStage systemStage) throws Exception;

    public Boolean isAvailable(SystemStage systemStage) throws Exception;

    public Boolean isAvailable(SystemStage systemStage) throws Exception;
}
```

And the ENUM looks like this

```java
public enum ReferenceSystem implements ReferenceController{
    UCMDB    (UcmdbFunctions.class),
    PROIPS   (ProIPSFunctions.class),
    KV       (KvFunctions.class),
    FISERVICE(FiServiceFunctions.class),
    COMMAND  (CommandFunctions.class),
    FII          (FiiFunctions.class);

    private Class<? extends ReferenceController> clazz;

    private ReferenceSystem(Class<? extends ReferenceController> controllerClass) {
        this.clazz = controllerClass;
    }

    public String displayName() {
        return displayName(Locale.GERMAN); 
    }

    public String displayName(Locale locale) {
        ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("EnumI18n", locale);
        return bundle.getString(toString()); 
    }

    public Class<? extends ReferenceController> getClassname() { return clazz; }

    @Override
    public Map<String, ReferenceElement> searchElements(String searchField, List<String> searchItems, SystemStage systemStage) throws Exception {
        Map<String, ReferenceElement> result = clazz.newInstance().searchElements(searchField, searchItems, systemStage);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String getStateMapping(String value) {
        try {
            return clazz.newInstance().getStateMapping(value);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean isAvailable(SystemStage systemStage) throws Exception {
        return clazz.newInstance().isAvailable(systemStage);
    }
}
```

At the moment I start the searches one after another. So my server hast to wait for a search to finish before it starts the next one. So the user has to wait very lang for the results to be presented.
This code starts the search

```java
    public static void performSingleSearch(ReferenceSystem referenceSystem, String searchField, List<String> searchValues, SystemStage systemStage) throws Exception {

        if(!isAvailable(referenceSystem, systemStage)) return;
        Map<String, ReferenceElement> result = new HashMap<>();
        try {
            result = referenceSystem.searchElements(searchField, searchValues, systemStage);
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            return;
        }
        if(result != null) orderResults(result, referenceSystem);
    }
```

The resultmap is the same object for all subsystems, so I need a system that all searches are started at once and are able to put their result into the result-object.

I hope it is possible to fill those objects nearly synchron so the User doesn't have to wait for all systems to finish.

Best regards
Daniel

Comment: [`ExecutorService.invokeAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection))

Comment: AtomicReference

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) you can use [`ListeningExecutorService.submit`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListeningExecutorService.html#submit-java.util.concurrent.Callable-) to submit a `Callable` wrapping each call to `searchElements` and collect the returned [`ListenableFuture`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture.html) instances in a list. Using [`Futures.allAsList`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#allAsList-com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture...-) the list can be converted into a future that returns a list of all results if all futures complete successfully and that completes unsuccessfully otherwise.

For example:

```
<T> void submitAll(
        Collection<Callable<T>> callables,
        Consumer<List<T>> onSuccess,
        Consumer<Throwable> onError,
        ExecutorService executor) {

    ListeningExecutorService decoratedExecutor = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(executor);

    List<ListenableFuture<T>> futures = Lists.newArrayList();
    for (Callable<T> callable : callables) {
        futures.add(decoratedExecutor.submit(callable));
    }

    FutureCallback<? super List<T>> cb = new FutureCallback<List<T>>() {
        public void onSuccess(List<T> result) {
            onSuccess.accept(result);
        }

        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            onError.accept(t);
        }
    };

    Futures.addCallback(Futures.allAsList(futures), cb, executor);
}
```